# What is this symbol, and how to reproduce it? (vertical bar with small footer)

Tags: symbols

How to reproduce this symbol, using Latex, that consists of a long vertical bar, on the right hand side of an expression, and some small text at the bottom, that defines some condition?

[image]

How to reproduce this symbol using latex?

Comment: It is given in LaTeX as `\vert` and it is extensible, as in `\left. \frac{...}{...}\right\vert_{...}`

Comment: @egreg fair enough. updated. how does the question look now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic building bloc  is `\vert`.  Because it is extensible, you have various ways to make it grow.

The various forms of `\[B/b]ig[g]` grow it a defined amount, whereas the use as part of a `\left...\right` context grows it to fit the content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
A\vert_x
\]
\[
\frac{A}{B}\bigr\vert_x
\frac{A}{B}\Bigr\vert_x
\frac{A}{B}\biggr\vert_x
\frac{A}{B}\Biggr\vert_x
\]
\[
\left.\frac{\displaystyle\frac{A}{B}}{\displaystyle1 + \frac{C}{D}}\right\vert_x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting—I've always used `\Big|_{x}`. Should I prevert to substitute `\vert` for `|`?

Comment: @wchargin In general `|` and `\vert` are completely equivalent. Indeed, `\vert` is defined as `\delimiter "026A30C` and the `\delcode` of `|` is `26A30C`, while its `\mathcode` is `026A`.

Answer (score 3):

Just for training

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \[
    +\Delta\mu_{i}\left.\frac{\partial E_{S\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^{2}_{S})}[f(S)]}{\partial \mu}\right\vert_{\mu=\mu_{S}}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]